# Need to break up CSV into smaller tables, depending on the value of one of my columns (time)

Tags: python, csv, geospatial, arcgis, arcpy

I have spatial tracking data (lat,long) with time stamps. If the time in between any two consecutive points is more than 2 hours, I can't analyze the data well, so I want to split up the dataset based on a user-specified time threshold. The ultimate goal is to upload them into ArcGIS as shapefiles (points). A lot of splitting is for splitting into equal # of rows or some common attribute, but this will be user specified and vary by data set. I'm super new to this, so don't have a script that isn't laughable but I'm toying with the idea of reading new data in and then creating empty lists, adding to them as long as the time (deltaseconds) is less than a certain amount (say 30 min, or 1800 sec). Once it hits that amount, saving that as a list and creating an output file and then starting with the next point into a new list...but there may be ways to do it while its still in CSV? This is a sample of data in csv:

```
Time                   Lat      Lng        Time     deltaseconds
9/12/2015   21:52   16.5033   -85.87527   0:00:00    0
9/12/2015   21:52   16.5033   -85.87524   0:00:01    1
9/12/2015   21:53   16.5033   -85.8752    0:00:55    55
```

Any help is appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.  In short, we expect you to make a good attempt at the problem first.  You've started the analysis well enough; now pick an attack and start coding.

Comment: Have you learned yet about the Python csv module?  That can simplify working with csv files.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying and failing. Here is the code I have so far (or my workflow) import csv
import os
import sys


f = open('V:\\finalproject\\Data\\rachel_honduras_Tracks.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
output_file = "V:\\finalproject\\Data\\editeddata\\newoutputfile.csv"

for row in reader:
       new_list = []
        read in new row
    new_list.append #read in rows and keep appending
        if deltaseonds < sys.argv[0]
       else stop
    output_file = new_list, #mustbe able to change name in output file everytime a new one is created
            then loop back to that and add a new list

Comment: Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays or [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframes might be much easier to deal with.  Is there a particular reason you want to process the data while it's still in a CSV (instead of loaded into arrays)?

Comment: Please edit your code into your initial question (using the grey `edit` button).  Four spaces in front of a line puts it into a `code` block.

Comment: This would be simple in `awk` if that is an option?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to breakup existing csv in multiple shapefiles based on time period range given in "deltaseconds" field. Firstly manually change field name 'deltaseconds' to 'deltasec' as shapefile can only take field length upto 10 characters. 
Now following is the script you can run in arcpy:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
def export_multiple_shps(workspace,file,t):
# Define workspace
    env.workspace=workspace
# Convert CSV to Shapefile, assuming that x-field is 'Lng' & y-field is 'Lat'
    MakeXYEventLayer_management(file, "Lng", "Lat", "tracking.shp")
# Count no. of rows in tracking shapefile
    arcpy.MakeTableView_management("tracking.shp","tableView")
    row_count=int(arcpy.GetCount_management("tableView").getOutput(0))
    k=1
    j=0
# Loop to export shapefiles after every t sec increment in 'deltasec' 
    for i in range(t,row_count,t):
        query1='\"deltasec\"<={}'.format(i)
        query2='\"deltasec\"<={}'.format(j)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tracking.shp","NEW_SELECTION",query1)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tracking.shp","REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION",query2)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("tracking.shp","tracking"+str(k)+".shp")
        j=i
        k+=1
# Executing function, by assuming csv is placed in "D:/data" with name "tracking.csv", & we want to export shapefile after every "1800 sec". You can change the inputs as per requirement
export_multiple_shps(workspace="D:/data",file="tracking.csv",t=1800)
```

Please let me know if your requirements are something else.